# $E$ is a Banach space for the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ where $\|x\|_{1} := \|x\|_{E}+\|T x\|_{F}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces

I'm reading a proof of closed graph theorem in textbook *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*.

> Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces. Let $T$ be a linear operator from $E$ into $F .$ Assume that the graph of $T, G(T)$, is closed in $E \times F$. Then $T$ is continuous.
>
> **Proof:** Consider, on $E$, the two norms
> $$
> \|x\|_{1}=\|x\|_{E}+\|T x\|_{F} \quad \text { and } \quad\|x\|_{2}=\|x\|_{E}
> $$
> It is easy to check, using the assumption that $G(T)$ is closed, that $E$ is a Banach space for the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$.

Could you verify if my proof, that $E$ is a Banach space for the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$, is correct?

---

**My attempt:** Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_1$, i.e., for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $$\|x_n -x_m \|_1 = \|x_n - x_m\|_{E}+\|T x_n -Tx_m\|_{F} < \varepsilon, \quad \forall m,n \ge N.$$

This implies $$\|x_n - x_m\|_{E} < \varepsilon \quad \text{and} \quad\|T x_n -Tx_m\|_{F} < \varepsilon, \quad \forall m,n \ge N.$$

Hence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_E$, and $(Tx_n)$ a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_F$. Because $E, F$ are complete. there are $x \in E, y\in F$ such that $x_n \to x$ w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_E$ and $Tx_n \to y$ w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_F$. On the other hand, $(x_n, Tx_n)$ is a sequence in $G(T)$ such that $(x_n, Tx_n) \to (x, y)$. This is because convergence in product topology is equivalent to component-wise convergence. Because $G(T)$ is closed, $(x, y) \in G(T)$ and thus $Tx = y$. It follows that $Tx_n \to Tx$ w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_F$. Hence $x_n \to x$ w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_1$.

Comment: I would love to give some feedback but I think its just completely correct

Comment: The way you concluded the exercise is perfect, but the way you imply that $x_n$ is cauchy also in norms $\|\cdot\|_E$ and $\|\cdot\|_F$ seems wrong to me. What if $x_n-x_m$ gets smaller and smaller in norm whereas $Tx_n-Tx_m$ gets bigger?

Comment: Davide, for Cauchy sequences, this is not possible. It looks possible for a fixed $\epsilon$, but the definition ensures that for all $\epsilon$ the sum should stay smaller than $\epsilon$ for big enough $n$ and $m.$